# JavaScript Disable "open","open new tab" and "copy" long press on anchor tag in iOS 8 safari

Tags: javascript, ios, css, contextmenu

I am trying to prevent "open", "open new tab", "add to read list" and "copy" options on anchor tag long press in iOS 8. I tried with `-webkit-touch-callout:none`, it's preventing only "save image" option only. The following code I tried but no use. I don't want to use `pointer-events:none`, on clicking of anchor tag I need to open one light box popup. Any help is appreciated

I tried the following options:

```
$('a').on("touchstart", function(e) {         
   e.preventDefault();
});

$('a').bind("touchstart", function(e) {       
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css file try following :

```
* {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Disable selection/copy in UIWebView */
}
```

Comment: @David, this CSS will hide only save image option, but still I can able to see "open","open new tab" and "copy" options